# file manager doesn't find folders

Tags: file-management, terminal

I am using a terminal, Termux, and Qute.
The terminal Qute shows me a path data/user/0/com.ddm.
In the file manager Cx File explorer I am not able to find them. In Android folder, there is a data folder with a lot of folders called com.something, as com.dropbox.android, but not the above cited folder, idem for folders of Termux. How can I find the wanted folders in file manager?

Comment: First is `/data/` and latter is `/data/media/0/Android/data/`. Names are same but those are different directories. If you want to access `/data/user/0/` from some file explorer, you need root access. If you just want to copy some files, do that from within Qute app, e.g. using `cp` command.

Comment: @Irfan Latif Thanks so much.  Do you know if it's possible to create and directories that are in the visible part of the phone with a non rooted Android terminal?

Comment: Visible part for non-root apps is `/sdcard`. Yes you can create directories there provided that the app owns storage permission.

Comment: @Irfan Latif very good thank you.